# Improper triple integral in spherical coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Compute the integral $$\int_{B^3(0,1)} (\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})^{-p}$$ when $x \ne0$ and $p<3.$

So $B^3(0,1)$ is just a sphere centered at the origin of radius $1$. Also in spherical coordinates I've managed to get the integral to the form $$\int \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{t}^{1}(r^2)^{-\frac{p}{2}} \cdot r^2 \cos(\varphi) \ dr \ d\theta \ d\varphi$$ as it is an improper integral I have to limit $t \to 0$ right? I'm not able to find the limits for $\varphi$. I tried solving for $\varphi$ from $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ with the appropriate substituion $x=r\cos(\theta)\sin(\varphi), y=r\sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi)$ and $z=r\cos(\varphi)$, but this ended up very messy and I couldn't solve it. Any hints on how to proceed here?

Comment: Since your domain of integration is the unit sphere centered at the origin, well $\varphi$ goes from $0$ to $\pi$.

Comment: Somehow I was thinking that I would have gone from $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: It's not correct, because otherwise you wouldn't get the negative $z's$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With usual shperical coordinates you would get it with $\sin(\varphi)$, so
$$\int_0^{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{t}^{1}(r^2)^{-\frac{p}{2}} \cdot r^2 \sin(\varphi) \ dr \ d\theta \ d\varphi=$$
$$= 2\pi \biggl[ -\cos(\varphi) \biggr]_0^{\pi}\int_{t}^{1}r^{2-p} \ dr =$$
which converges if and only if $p-2<1$ which means $p<3$, an it is:
$$= 4\pi\int_{t}^{1}r^{2-p}= 4\pi \biggl[ \frac{r^{3-p}}{3-p} \biggr]_0^1=\frac{4\pi}{3-p}$$

Comment: Do you agree with this?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to find the reasoning for why it is an improper integral. Could you elaborate on this a bit?

Comment: Simply becouse in the original integral you have that the function inside of it goest to $\infty$ as $(x,y,z)\to (0,0,0) \in B^3(0,1)$. So you have to see if it actually converges in the "generalized" sense of the integral.